# Naming excel sheet based on data in the sheet using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, time, datetime
import numpy as np

####IMPORT FILES####

df=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/data.csv")
df1=pd.read_excel("C:/Users/user.xlsx")

####FILTERS####

data1 = df1[df1['SAG/non-SAG'] == "SAG"]
data = data1[data1['MEDIA TYPE'].isin(["TV/OTT", "TV", "TV "])]
c = np.array(data['ISCI or AD-ID #']) 


for i in c:
    c = np.append(c, i[0:-1])
    
print(c)
    
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
for i in c:
    df_new = pd.concat([df_new, df[df['Isci Code'] == i]])
    
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
for i in c:
    df_new = pd.concat([df_new, df[df['Isci Code'] == i]])
   

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        
for i,key in enumerate(c):    
    print(key)
    df_new.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key)
writer.save()
```

And this is the output I am getting:

Excel output:

[image]

I have to group the highlighted ISCIs together and make sure the only ISCIs in the excel worksheet are the same as the name of the worksheet. For example: sheet XXH should contain row 2 and 10, sheet CCH should contain row 5, sheet AAH should contain row 3 and 6 and so on.

(Basically, code XXH and XX mean the same. We can ignore the last digit 'H' when grouping the ISCIs. )